# Edit a page template of wordpress in HTML

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I want to edit the post page of my website. The problem is that I do not know PHP. I know HTMl and CSS. When I go to the "view page source" of the page I can clearly see the html and css codes, but I can't find the page in my ftp file manager. I know that we can not see the PHP code in "view page source" and the pages are stored in database. I want to know how I can edit the basic template of a post page with HTML and CSS to change the div, image and other things?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your challenge here, unfortunately you will have to learn PHP in order to make any edits. PHP code is read by the web server and used to generate HTML. There's no way to edit the HTML since it's always generated and mostly when the page is requested.

Imagine that the HTML is a meal, PHP is the ingredients and recipe and the web server is the chef. What you want to do is like asking to have less spice in a meal after the meal is made. You have to tell the chef to use less spice before he cooks it. So you have to know the recipe and change the ingredients before the chef prepares and cooks the meal

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel for your great explaination amd awesome example..:)

Comment: You're welcome @SyedNazmusSadat I feel that if you're making minor edits you should be able to read some of the php and make meaningful changes. What are you looking to do?